# Update on Aggregate in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

i am trying to toggle a boolean value inside a object, which is a subdocument, i am having hard time to update a particular object within an array.

**Document:**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("54afaabd88694dc019d3b628")
"Invitation" : [ 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54af6ce091324fd00f97a15f"),
        "__t" : "USER",
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b4ceb50fc380001bea1752"),
        "Accepted" : false
    }, 
    {
        "__v" : 0,
        "ID" : ObjectId("54afac5412f5fdcc007a5c4d"),
        "__t" : "USER",
        "_id" : ObjectId("54b4cebe0fc380001bea1753"),
        "Accepted" : false
    }
],
```

**Controller:**

```
User.aggregate([{$match: {_id: ObjectId(54afaabd88694dc019d3b628)}},{$unwind: '$Invitation'},{$project: {_id: '$_id',Invitation: '$Invitation'}}],function(err,results){

    function updateInvitation(_id){

                var query = {'_id': _id, 'Invitation.ID': ObjectId("54af6ce091324fd00f97a15f")};
                var operator = {$inc: {'Invitation.Accepted': 1}}; 
                User.update(query,operator,{multi:true},function(err,updated){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log('updating'+updated);
                });
            }
            res.jsonp(results);
            updateInvitation(results[0]._id);
});
```

i tried using $set but it didnt worked out as whole Invitation array got replaced with '**Accepted = 1**'
How can i toggle '**Accepted**' field of the document with particular '**ID**'.

```
Invitation.$.Accepted
```

Positional operator doesnot apply to field containing array so can't iterate to **Accepted** field

**EDIT:**

```
User.find({_id: req.user._id},'Invitation',function(err,docs){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(docs);
    var results = [];
    async.each(docs,function(doc,err) {
        if(err){
            console.log('error'+ err);
        }
        async.each(docs.Invitation,function(invite,callback) {
console.log('second async');
            User.update(
                { '_id': doc._id, 'Invitation._id': invite._id },
                { '$set': {'Invitation.$.Accepted': !invite.Accepted}},
                function(err,doc) {
                    results.push(doc);
                    console.log('updated'+doc);
                    callback(err);
                }
            );
        });
    },function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);
        console.log(results);
    });

});
```

The control is not getting inside second async.each, error is thrown on first async here is the error:

```
error-function () {
        if (called) throw new Error("Callback was already called.");
        called = true;
        fn.apply(root, arguments);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think that even as a feeder query the aggregation framework is the right operation to use here. All you are doing is "denormalizing" the array as individual documents. There really should be no need. Just fetch the document instead:

```
var query = {}; // whatever criteria

Users.find(query,"Invitation",function(err,docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

    var results = [];        

    async.each(docs,function(doc,callback) {
        async.each(docs.Invitation,function(invite,callback) {
            Users.findOneAndUpdate(
                { "_id": doc._id, "Invitation._id": invite._id },
                { "$set": { "Invitation.$.Accepted": !invite.Accepted } },
                function(err,doc) {
                   results.push( doc );
                   callback(err);
                }
            );
        },callback);
    },function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);

        console.log(results);
    });    

});
```

So there is no problem iterating the list of documents in a response for what you are doing, it's just that you also want to iterate the array members as well. The catch is when issuing any kind of `.update()` that you need to be aware then the asynchronous call is complete.

So I'm using [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) but you probably want [async.eachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachLimit) to control the looping. The matching of the element comes from the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator, corresponding to the matched array element in the query.

It's just JavaScript code, so simply "toggle" the value with `!invite.accepted` which will inverse it. For additional fun, return the "results" array by pushing the modified document from [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: thanks for answer but i am getting this error on async.each
https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/610

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat That issue is about an undefined array object? So which array object is undefined here? The results of `.find()` should be returning documents or the query is wrong. If the inner "Invitation" array is undefined then you can test for that value before submitting to async.each.

Comment: @NeilLunn-query on `.find()` returning Invitation array which is already defined i tested it on `console.log(docs)` but still getting this weird error

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Sounds like you are doing something different to the code in the listing. Try working with the listing as given first to see where else things could be going wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn-can you explain me the logic of using two async.each please?

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Very simple. The outer iterates the "documents" from the `.find()` query. The "inner" iterates the "array members", hence "Invitation". It's an array in the document still and not flattened out like you were doing processing `$unwind`. It's logical and a lot faster than processing from the aggregate source. That's what I said right at the beginning.

Comment: @NeilLunn-I have tried above code but seriously i am getting error of async when i did `console.log(err);` please help me with this i am editing question of what i did

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat You cannot be running the code in the listing I have given as I told you before. Your problems are likely due to how you are interpreting this. I an no-one else can diagnose just based on your comments. If you have another problem then post another question.

Comment: @NeilLunn- ok fine just have a look over the error above, just tell me what's  that implying? and i got your point of posting another question but what's the purpose of posting another one when i am getting error in answer you provided?

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat Because you coded it wrong. The second argument to async.each iterator function is the callback to be called on completion. That is not the code that I wrote. Spot the difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69102/discussion-between-shailesh-shekhawat-and-neil-lunn).

Answer (score 0):

Use the positional update operator for this:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

```
User.update(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("54afaabd88694dc019d3b628"),
        "Invitation": {"$elemMatch": {"ID" : ObjectId("54af6ce091324fd00f97a15f"), "Accepted":false}}
    },
    {
        "$set" : {
            "Invitation.$.Accepted" : true
        }
    },{multi:false, upsert:false, safe:true}, function (err, numAffectedDocuments){
      // TODO
    }
);
```

Note : you don't need the aggregation step since it actually does nothing.

Comment: i already tried using positional operator but got this error
 'Cannot apply the positional operator field containing an array'

Comment: @shaileshshekhawat that happens because the field to update needs to also be in the query. I edited the code in the answer to correct that.