# Filter subdocument and trigger

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have collection of objects inside an invitation, having hard time to filter particular object and trigger it's boolean field.

**Document:**

```
"Invitation" : [ 
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "userID" : ObjectId("54afaabd88694dc019d3b628"),//ObjectId of personA
    "__t" : "USER",
    "_id" : ObjectId("54b5022b583973580c706784"),
    "Accepted" : false
}, 
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "userID" : ObjectId("54af6ce091324fd00f97a15f"),//ObjectId of personB
    "__t" : "USER",
    "_id" : ObjectId("54bde39cdd55dd9016271f14"),
    "Accepted" : false
}
]
```

here i have only two objects inside Invitation array,it can be more than two.
Let's say **personA** and **personB** send me Invitation, so two different invitation objects are inserted into database having different fields, with **objectId** of both persons(**userID** in above document), now if i accept only invitation of personA, it should **trigger accepted field** of personA object only, here is what i tried so far, but not working as per expectation.

**Controller:**

```
User.find({_id: req.user._id},'Invitation',function(err,docs) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
}
    var results = [];

    async.each(docs,function(doc,callback) {

        async.each(doc.Invitation,function(invite,callback) {
            User.findOneAndUpdate(
                {'_id': doc._id, 'Invitation._id': invite._id},
                {'$set': {'Invitation.$.Accepted': !invite.Accepted}},
                function(err,doc) {
                    results.push(doc);
                    callback(err);
                }
            );
        },callback);
    },function(err) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);

        console.log('end'+results);
    });

});
```

finally i am looking for a query which can be used to filter a **single element or object**, like if i accept invitation of **personA** then Accepted field of personA object should be set to true.
i would be really helpful if some logic is provided.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a very clear question. But it seems all you really need to do here is just match the only sub-document you want to update in the first place:

```js
User.find(
   { 
       "_id": "req.user._id",
       "Invitation._id": personA.id
   },
   { "Invitation.$": 1 },
   function(err,docs) {
     // and continue
   }
);
```

This is the form of the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in a "projection" context. Where only the "singular" matched element is returned.

Once you have a "singular" result, then all the other code works as designed.

I should know after all because I wrote it for you. Not that you are paying any decent respect to that.

[Update on Aggregate in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27961171/2313887)

[Toggle boolean value of subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28043602/2313887)

Or `personA.userID` or whatever makes it work.

Just use the unique identifier for the "user" where you expect that to match the query conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
db.user.update({"invitation.userID": 1}, {"$set" : {"invitation.$.Accepted" : true}});
```

Replacing the value 1 with the user ID you want to update.

The code is in the syntax of MongoShell, simply convert to driver syntax you are using

The operator used was the `$`. According to the documentation: The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. To project, or return, an array element from a read operation, see the $ projection operator.

For more details see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: i tried your code inside the code i posted, it results with `null` value, as for iteration i have to use async.each, so can you help me on how to scale answer with async.each